# Windows Server 2019 RemoteFX COM port redirection does not work, Windows Server 2012 it works

Tags: windows-server-2012-r2, rdp, windows-server-2019

Have Windows7 workstation with  a USB COM port device installed.

From this Windows7 workstation I RDP to Windows Server 2012 terminal server and all devices are redirected through RDP correctly.

If I RDP from same workstation Windows7 to Windows Server 2019 terminal server, using the same GPO in domain, I do not get these COM ports redirected.

Both RDP connections have the COM port redirection checked ON, and I see the device on the workstation OK. (MSTSC.msc/Local resources/ Other Supported RemoteFX devices/COM3).

Does Windows Server 2019 need to allow anytjhing special in GPO to accept COM ports redirected. Windows7 workstation is using RDP 8.1 RDP version, as on Windows Server 2012 it works OK.

Or it requires something additional in GPO to be allowed.
Any ideas?

Comment: ...tested the same scenario but from other machine : Win2019 to WIN2012 -all OK, from WIN2019 to Terminal Win2019 - not working.any ideas?

Comment: RemoteFX for device redirection is a dead end technology. You need to use Discrete Device Assignment instead. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/virtualization/hyper-v/plan/plan-for-deploying-devices-using-discrete-device-assignment

Comment: Thanks, but I am using win7 to redirect the USB device,so I guess only remotefx is solution for me.

Comment: There aren't any options for Windows 7. It was End Of Life in 2020 and off topic.

Comment: Thanks Greg, but my question is whether Windows Server 2019 can accept COM port redicrected in RDP, or it needs anything special to allow it.....With your answer we turned the probelm upside down (Discrete Device Assignment) ....Windows7 RDP to Windows Server 2012 works OK, so there is nothing wrong with this even Dead end Technology, the only question is if there is a way how to make Port redirection work on Windows Server 2019....Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue on a virtual server I had with a user USB to serial cable.

Two key points that can resolve your issue:

Make sure the server hardware got a USB controller configured for him, the redirection will silently fail as it would be seen as a remote USB device, but the server lack the USB controller to redirect it.

Secondly, if the USB controller is there, log in one time with an admin account to have the USB driver install for the redirection.

Comment: Thanks, not quiete sure if understood correctly, but:1.the usb is fully installed, yet working to 2012, so it should be ok even to 2019 VM I guess(I can see in mstsc.msc/local resources/other supported remoteFx devices that I am redirecting it. 2. Tried to login as admin offcourse before, no luck.....is there maybe a way to check if the remoteFx is working and allowed in the RDP stream on remote OS side?...I am suspecting some gpo settings for 2019 which maybe need to be different if compared to 2012..